Why does static analysis not resolve this type?
Forgive me if I get any terminology incorrect. I'm quite new to Dart and especially generics in Dart. However, I don't understand why I get an error with the following code.
class SomeEvent{}

class Init extends SomeEvent{}

class Foo<Event>{
  void on<E extends Event>(){}
}

class Bar<E extends SomeEvent> extends Foo<E>{
  Bar(){
    on<Init>(); //<--- Error here
  }
}

Specifically, the error is the following:

'Init' doesn't conform to the bound 'E' of the type parameter 'E'.

And from what I understand, that means that the Init type argument is not a subtype of E. However (also, from what I understand), E extends SomeEvent constrains E to be any type of SomeEvent of which Init is a subtype of. What confuses me more is that even on dartpad.dev, when I click on E in extends Foo<E> it says:

E extends SomeEvent

So what am I missing and how can this be fixed? I would like calls to super method on defined in class Foo to be accept any subtype of the type argument passed to Foo.

I think you might have two E types.  Try class Bar<EE extends....

That sounds like a great question. Let me try to explain it in simple words.
When you have a generic class like Foo, the type parameter Event can be anything.
When you extend Foo<E> in Bar<E>, E can be any subtype of SomeEvent. The problem arises because on<E extends Event>() in Foo is too flexible compared to the constraint in Bar.
Let's take an example
Consider this scenario:

Foo: A generic class that handles events of any type that extends Event.
Bar: A class that extends Foo and tries to handle a specific type of event (SomeEvent).

Now, if you allow Bar<E extends SomeEvent> to call on<Init>(), Dart needs to ensure Init is always a valid subtype of E. However, E can be any type extending SomeEvent, not just Init.
Here's a trouble-ful example:
class SomeEvent {}
class Init extends SomeEvent {}
class AnotherEvent extends SomeEvent {}

class Foo<Event> {
  void on<E extends Event>() {}
}

class Bar<E extends SomeEvent> extends Foo<E> {
  Bar() {
    on<Init>(); // This is problematic
  }
}

void main() {
  // Suppose we create an instance of Bar with AnotherEvent
  Bar<AnotherEvent> bar = Bar<AnotherEvent>();
  bar.on<Init>(); // Error: Init is not a subtype of AnotherEvent
}

As you can clearly see, Init is not subtype of AnotherEvent - but both are subtypes of SomeEvent.
Fix
Just in case if you're looking for a fix such a way that on<Init> should work, you can tweak the the definition of Bar class as following:
class Bar<E extends SomeEvent> extends Foo<SomeEvent>{
  Bar(){
    on<Init>(); // Works now
  }
}

or
class Bar extends Foo<SomeEvent> { // No generic parameter here
  Bar() {
    on<Init>(); // Works now
  }
}

By this, you're basically ensuring that Init is always a valid type for the on method, as Init is a subtype of SomeEvent.
Hope this helps :)

Yes, thanks. This really makes me understand the problem. So there is no way to make it work as I'd like?

You got it right. There's no way Dart analyzer be happy about your code. As said in the answer, it's because by the definition Bar<E extends SomeEvent> extends Foo<E>, E can be any class extended from SomeEvent and Init might not have to be extended from E. So, you know the analyzer error persists :)

Things work out fine when E is SomeEvent - because E extends SomeEvent and Init also extends SomeEvent. That's case which I basically proposed as Fix in the original answer.

This definitely answers the question I asked. I should have mentioned though that the definition for Foo is within a library I cannot directly modify. So I suppose I was really wondering if there was a way to extend the library's class as explained. But I suppose not. Thanks.
